# How to find if there's a value in a column of a view in xPages

Tags: view, xpages

I am using a view in an xPages.  There's 10 fields at the top that allow you to make a search.
This view show the results in 10 columns , let's say A to J.

Sometimes, I have values for 10 columns but sometimes, there's values in just some of those columns.  By Example A, B, C, F, G, H, I, J.

The view is populated by a SELECT in a Oracle table.

Is there a way to only put visible the columns that contains at least 1 value in the search result.

No sure I am clear enough, but if you have any idea or need a better example, please let me know.

Thanks for your input.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to hide a column based on the column value?

Comment: yes let's say I have 10 rows of values and the 10 rows don't have a value in column A, I would like to hide this column.  If there's at least 1 value in that column, I would want to see it.

Comment: but if you hide the column then the other 9 rows will not show?  Did you mean you want to hide the row if there is a column value missing. Sorry If do not understand

Comment: I mean if all the result doesn't contain a value in column C, I want to hide column C.   Let's say I have a search box with Civic No , Street, City, Postal Code and Unit.  Most of the time there's no unit, so in my result I would want to show this column, only when the search result contains a unit.

Comment: Ok. Got it. I would create a script using Jquery that on page load hides the column if there is no value present in any of the rows in that column. You could of course also check the data serverside prior to displaying the view but that would probably give you poor performance.  Hope it helps

Comment: I'd use a repeat control bound to JDBC data source to display the data. It would use a computed text (set to display HTML) and use a little javascript to set parent column header's display in case value is not null/blank. hope it helps.

Comment: UX point of view: if you hide "random" column, users can have problems to identify which column is missing and why...